Electrolyte in Electrolysis of CuSO4
I have 2 questions regarding electrolyte used in electrolytic refining of copper:

I was reading metallurgy of copper and I noticed that in electrolytic refining we use acidified aqueous $\ce{CuSO_4}$ as electrolyte.


My question is: why do we use acidified and not just aqueous solution of $\ce{CuSO_4}$?

Since $\ce{CuSO_4}$ is soluble in water, so it would dissociate into ions readily, and hence conduct electricity. So I think acidification is not done just for increasing conductivity, or is it??
Or is there any other reason??
Please point out if there are any mistakes in my thought process.

Also, I noticed that the acid used to acidify is $\ce{H_2SO_4}$ and not any other acid. Why so??


Is it something to do with common Sulphate ions in $\ce{H_2SO_4}$ and $\ce{CuSO_4}$??


Late edition:
Amit also wonders why we use $\ce{HNO3}$ as acid in Electrolysis of $\ce{AgNO3}$ but not other acids. Is it only because the acid $(\ce{HNO3})$ and the salt $(\ce{AgNO3})$ have the same anion?

Consider what would happen as impurities in the copper react with CuSO4 -- what would happen to the concentration of SO4-- ions?

I didn't get your point ...can you explain please ?

Are all sulfates soluble? Look up "precipitate" as connected to chemistry.

So you're making the point that impurities might ppt sulphate ions and so H2SO4 is added rather any other acid ....huh??.... But why do we care about sulphate ions in solutions as long as we have Cu+2 ....why H2SO4 ....HNO3 would do the same...hm??

Again, consider the purpose of the process -- one wants impurities to precipitate into the sludge at the bottom, not to plate onto the cathode. Many nitrates are highly soluble.

I think answer to your first question is is provided here. Ivan Neretin pointed there:

Once dissolved in water, $\ce{CuSO4}$ would dissociate into ions completely, no matter whether or not you acidify it. The role of acid is just to prevent hydrolysis.
There are more than one hydrolysis reactions can happen there. Few examples are:


Autoionization of water: $\ce{2H2O <=> H3O+ + 2 OH-}$ where $K_\mathrm{w} = 1.0 \times 10^{-14}$. Providing extra $\ce{H3O+}$ ions reduces the concentration of $\ce{OH-}$, which prevents the possibility of $\ce{OH-}$ oxidizing/reducing according to $\ce{O2 + 2H2O + 4e- <=> 4 OH-}$ where $E^\circ = \pu{0.401 V}$.
Hydrolysis of $\ce{Cu^2+}$: The trace amount of the presence of $\ce{OH-}$ can cause the hydrolysis of $\ce{Cu^2+}$ according to the equation $\ce{Cu^2+ + 2OH- -> Cu(OH)2}$. The $K_\mathrm{sp}$ of $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$ is so small that you may slowly loose your $\ce{Cu^2+}$ concentration $(K_\mathrm{sp} = 1.6 \times 10^{-19})$. As explain above, adding extra $\ce{H3O+}$ ions reduces the concentration of $\ce{OH-}$ eliminating this possibility.
Also, dissolution of atmospheric $\ce{CO2}$: During the electrolysis, the surface of the solution is open to air so that dissolution of atmospheric $\ce{CO2}$ can be possible as $\ce{CO2 + H2O -> H2CO3 <=>[H2O] HCO3- + H3O+}$. Again, adding extra $\ce{H3O+}$ ions reverses this process.

The answer to your second question is using only sulfuric acid prevents the release of toxic gases such as $\ce{Cl2}$ (from hydrochloric acid). Those acids (e.g., $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{HNO3}$) has counter ions capable of oxidizing/reducing potentials compatible with water. Therefore, anode may release not only oxygen as the product ($\ce{O2 +  4H3O+ = + 4e- <=> 3H2O}$, $E^\circ = \pu{1.229 V}$), but also other toxic gases with competing reactions (e.g., $\ce{Cl2 + 2e- <=> 2Cl-}$, $E^\circ = \pu{1.358 V}$). For sulfate ion to reduce/oxidize competitively has a very minimal chance.

Amit has lately added a third question:

Why we use $\ce{HNO3}$ as acid in Electrolysis of $\ce{AgNO3}$ but not other acids? Is it only because the acid $(\ce{HNO3})$ and the salt $(\ce{AgNO3})$ have the same anion?

The simple answer is yes, since they have both common anion, why should we complicate with the situation with adding additional anions to compete for anode reaction? On the other hand, anions of common halo-acids ($\ce{HCl, HBr}$ and $\ce{HI}$) are not only compete for anode with water, but also they efficiently give water insoluble precipitates with $\ce{Ag+}$ ions (look up qualitative analysis of inorganic salts). The anion of other available common mineral acid, $\ce{H2SO4}$, would not compete with water for anode reaction, but it will precipitate silver as $(\ce{Ag2SO4})$ to complicate the situation. The solid $(\ce{Ag2SO4})$ has $K_\mathrm{sp}$ of $1.2 \times 10^{-5}$ (about $\pu{800 mg}$ in $\pu{100 mL}$ of water) thus concentration of $\ce{AgNO3}$ would be limited during electrolysis.

You answered my 1st question completely... Especially your 2nd point ... awesome..thanks ...but my 2nd question still stands ....as in like Electrolysis of AgNO3 we use Dil HNO3 as acid ... Why this then.... The acid and soluble salt have same anion.... Any insights??

Your question about $\ce{AgNO3}$ is not included in your original question. You can ask it in separate question or include here as late edition.

I'm new to SE ...can you do that late edition thing for me ...thanks in advance

So Mathew tell me one more thing ,,,,we generally use common anions as in electrolytes as in salt ,,,so is that for the same reason ,,,that we don't have to think much about solubility and other complications ,,,hm?
